# Jenkins hangs during git clone on windows slave

Tags: windows, git, jenkins, freeze

Jenkins has recently starting hanging during builds on our windows slaves. It gets as far as trying to fetch the tags and never proceeds beyond that.

Log:

```
    [EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
    Started by an SCM change
    [EnvInject] - Preparing an environment for the build.
    [EnvInject] - Keeping Jenkins system variables.
    [EnvInject] - Keeping Jenkins build variables.
    Executing 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/Common7/Tools/VsDevCmd.bat'.
    [Jenkins] $ C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/Common7/Tools/VsDevCmd.bat 
    [EnvInject] - Script executed successfully.
    [EnvInject] - Injecting contributions.
    Building remotely on build-02 (Windows dotnet) in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\zzzzz.develop
    [EnvInject] - Unset unresolved 'USERNAME' variable.
    [WS-CLEANUP] Deleting project workspace...
    [WS-CLEANUP] Done
    Cloning the remote Git repository
    Cloning repository https://bitbucket.org/xxxxx/zzzzz.git 
     > git init C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\zzzzz.develop # timeout=10 
    Fetching upstream changes from https://bitbucket.org/xxxxx/zzzzz.git 
     > git --version # timeout=10 
    using .gitcredentials to set credentials 
     > git config --local credential.username deployment # timeout=10 
     > git config --local credential.helper store --file=\"C:\Windows\TEMP\git1405350454459766899.credentials\" # timeout=10 
     > git -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress https://bitbucket.org/xxxxx/zzzzz.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

This has working perfectly for several months and this behaviour started yesterday.

I'm running Jenkins 2.8 on Windows, with Git 2.8.4. I've tried downgrading Jenkins to 2.7 and 1.651, and downgrading Git to 2.7 and 1.9 - same results.

If I run these commands on the machine from the workspace folder they work just fine.

I can't even see what the problem might be as there is no error response from Jenkins or Git.

Apologies if this is a duplicate of a previous question - the only questions I could see related to Jenkins hanging with git related to linux.

I've tried following the instructions from the Git plugin page but they don't seem to relate as there are no Jenkins id_rsa files anywhere on the server

Answer (score 0):

try downloading [git for windows](https://git-for-windows.github.io/) and replacing your current git.exe with the new downloaded git.exe

(for more details: http://www.geekytidbits.com/cygwin-sshd-msysgit-happy/)